# Posix threads, child returns error

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

If I have program with a main thread and a function running in a separated detached thread. If something in the detached thread is returning something > 0 
will only the child thread exit or the main thread too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Posix thread returns `void *` (ie. a pointer), so it cannot return anything less than zero since it's not an integer.

In any case, the return value from a detached thread is always ignored, and the process will not exit whatever the value.

Answer (score 1):

Only the child thread exits, unless it calls `exit()`, that is.